# SpriteKit library BUG: battery drain (Energy Impact is High / Very High) [WORKAROUND]

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I understand that stackoverflow is rather a question-answer informational resource, but I also believe its core idea is solution sharing in the first place. And, as I found a tricky bug in Apple's SpriteKit library, and a workaround for that bug, I share the solution with you.

Also, I filed a bug report to Apple via https://bugreport.apple.com/, but the 1-trillion company seem not to care much - it's been almost two weeks since the report, and the bug is still open, and not a single comment / update was given from the Apple crew.

### TLDR;

SpriteKit goes into enormous energy consumption if your game supports landscape mode only, and the order of UISupportedInterfaceOrientations landscape values in your Info.plist file is 'wrong' (!). If UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight goes first and UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft goes second - you are in trouble.

The workaround is:

1. Select your Info.plist in the project navigator -> Open As -> Source Code. Find the key: UISupportedInterfaceOrientations
2. Make sure the order of values is the following:

(LandscapeLeft goes FIRST)

```
<string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
<string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
```

That's it.

### BUG REPRODUCE STEPS

(for those only who are curious and have some extra free time)

1. Launch XCode, create a brand new project of type 'Game'

   - language: Swift
   - game technology: SpriteKit
   - uncheck Integrate GamePlayKit
   - uncheck Include Unit Tests
   - uncheck Include UI Tests
2. In target general settings

   - uncheck Device Orientation: Portrait
   - check Requires full screen
3. Remove files: GameScene.sks, Actions.sks (Move to trash)
4. Replace the content of GameScene.swift with the following

code:

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

    fileprivate let nodeSizeUnit: CGFloat = 50

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        let layer = getLayer()
        let nodeWithBody = getItemWithBody()

        layer.addChild(nodeWithBody)
        addChild(layer)     
    }

    fileprivate func getLayer() -> SKNode {
        let layerSize = CGSize(width: nodeSizeUnit * 3, height: nodeSizeUnit * 3)
        let layer = SKSpriteNode(texture: nil, color: UIColor.blue, size: layerSize)
        layer.position = CGPoint(x: size.width / 2, y: size.height / 2)

        return layer
    }

    fileprivate func getItemWithBody() -> SKNode {
        let bodySize = CGSize(width: nodeSizeUnit, height: nodeSizeUnit)
        let body = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: bodySize)

        body.isDynamic = false
        body.affectedByGravity = false
        body.categoryBitMask = 0
        body.collisionBitMask = 0
        body.contactTestBitMask = 0

        let item = SKSpriteNode(texture: nil,
                                color: SKColor.gray,
                                size: CGSize(width: nodeSizeUnit * 2, height: nodeSizeUnit * 2))
        item.physicsBody = body

        return item
    }
}
```

5. Replace the content of GameViewController with the following

code:

```
import SpriteKit

class GameViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let view = self.view as! SKView? {
            let scene = GameScene()
            scene.size = UIScreen.main.nativeBounds.size
            scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
            view.presentScene(scene)

            view.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

            view.showsPhysics = true
            view.showsFPS = true
            view.showsNodeCount = true
            view.showsDrawCount = true
        }
    }
}
```

6. Connect a physical device available, run the build on that device. Make sure to set build's Deployment Target according to you device.

**UPD: Make sure the device iOS is -below- 12.0, otherwise you'll get high energy impact regardless of UISupportedInterfaceOrientations parameters order. Looks like SpriteKit has even another, iOS-version-related, energy consumption bug.**

7. Go to the Debug Navigator (Cmd + 7), switch to the Energy Impact section. The average Energy Impact is low. Fine at this point.
8. Stop the build, go to target settings. uncheck Device Orientation: Landscape Left. Aaaand check it again. Yes, you read it right: first uncheck, then check. Now, you are doomed.
9. Run the build, go to the Debug Navigator (Cmd + 7), switch to the Energy Imact section. Now, it grows frorm 'Low' to 'High' in a blink of an eye, and ends up 'Very High'. How cool is that?
10. Stop the build. Select your Info.plist in the project navigator -> Open As -> Source Code. Find the key: UISupportedInterfaceOrientations. You'll see the following:

(LandscapeLeft goes SECOND):

```
<array>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>    
</array>
```

change it to:

```
<array>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>    
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
</array>
```

(LandscapeLeft goes FIRST)

11. Run the build, go to the Debug Navigator (Cmd + 7), switch to the Energy Impact section. The average Energy Impact is low. Yay.

You can play the UISupportedInterfaceOrientations key yourself, changing the order of params and watching the energy impact change accordingly.